# como cambiar el varlor Html y Js

Tags: javascript, html5

hola chicos como podria cambiar de valor con opciones predifinidas con "select" a este codigo ".openMidiOut("quiero cambiar este valor")"
no queria molestar pero me vi cientos de videos y no le encuentro la forma, Gracias.
``````<

```
<select name="select">
  <option value="1">Value 1</option> 
  <option value="2" selected>Value 2</option>
  <option value="3">Value 3</option>
</select>
<script><!--
var select;
var select = x;
let piano = JZZ().openMidiOut("quiero cambiar este valor").or('Cannot open MIDI Out port!')

 
function play() {
 
   piano.ch("0")
        .control("127", 100)
     
}
--></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No se entiende la duda, por favor explica mejor

Comment: Perdon! estuve renegando con tratar de pegar el codigo, lo que quiero hace una lista de opciones                                                                                     
<select name="select">
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
  <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select> y para que me pueda cambiar el valor donde va openMidiOut("value")

Answer (score 0):

Primero hay que asociar un evento para cuando se cambia el valor del select, y luego se accede al texto seleccionado con:

```
elementoSelect.options[elementoSelect.selectedIndex].text
```

Este es un código genérico:

```js
//referenciamos el select
var miSelect = document.getElementById("mi-select");

//evento para cuando cambia el valor del select
miSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
  //obtenemos el texto y el valor que se seleccionaron
  var textoSeleccionado = miSelect.options[miSelect.selectedIndex].text,
      valorSeleccionado = miSelect.options[miSelect.selectedIndex].value;
  
  //como prueba, lo mostramos en consola
  console.log('Se seleccionó', textoSeleccionado, 'valor=',valorSeleccionado);
});
```

```html
<select name="select" id="mi-select">
  <option value="1">Value 1</option> 
  <option value="2" selected>Value 2</option>
  <option value="3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

En tu caso, en vez de imprimir con `console.log()`, usarías:

```
JZZ().openMidiOut(textoSeleccionado)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la pronta respuesta, estuve haciendo pruebas de todas las posibilidades con tu codigo y no me lo toma, sera que entra como texto? JZZ().openMidiOut(textoSeleccionado) JZZ().openMidiOut(valorSeleccionado) y nada

Comment: Claro que es un texto lo que estarías pasando como parámetro. Para depurarlo, pondría un `console.log()` en ese lugar del código, para verificar si llega el valor que estás buscando. Si llega bien, entonces será un error con `JZZ.openMidiOut()`, que desconozco qué es, y que probablemente sea para realizar una nueva publicación con esa pregunta.

Comment: Otra cosa que probaría es si realmente funciona llamar a `JZZ.openMidiOut('Value 2')`, para descartar que sea eso.

Comment: JZZ().openMidiOut("1").or("") de esta forma si funciona :/

Comment: aun sigo buscando algun metodo de poder introducir solo un valor numerico

Comment: `JZZ().openMidiOut(valorSeleccionado)` envía sólo el string con un número. O es que tenés un error en algún otro lado, o no entendí la pregunta.

Comment: JZZ me tira un error que debo ingresar valores numericos, desde mi nula experiencia me da a entender es que entra como string y tiene que ser numerico, se me ocurrio una idea de crear una variable con todos los num y invocarlos con select pero no se como hacerlo var num = ["1", "2", "3", "4" etc];

Comment: @GabrielLenzina eso es una pregunta completamente diferente a la que hiciste: cómo convertir un string a entero, y se resuelve con `parseInt()` ... `JZZ().openMidiOut(parseInt(valorSeleccionado))` .. pero debería estar en una pregunta diferente a esta en todo caso

Comment: de todos modos muchas gracias, pero no funciono, no marca ningun error sera que lo tengo que caputrar antes?

Comment: @GabrielLenzina no tengo la menor idea. Perdón, pero preguntaste cómo obtener el valor de un select y eso fue lo que respondí... El resto de tus problemas tienen que ver con una librería que jamás usé... Te invito a publicar una nueva pregunta que sea específicamente sobre eso y que te pueda ayudar otra persona. No tiene sentido que me sigas preguntando a mí en comentarios, cuando el problema original que tenías ya está resuelto

Comment: Gracias nuevamente por todas las respuestas! me acabo de dar cuenta que funciona, pero si cambio a otro valor ya no cambia, muchas gracias

Comment: descubri que siempre me toma la primer opcion de "select" y no se actualiza, si llego a encontrar como corregirlo, lo publico para que les siva de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo consegui por si agluno le sirve, tuve que crear una "funcion" para poder obtener el dato y en select utilizar "onchange" muchas gracias a @Pollo por ayudarme un fenomeno!